# Angularjs: How to assign output of a directive which is an array in loop.

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

Angularjs: How to assign output of a directive which is an array in loop. Ex: in ng-repeat, I have added a directive. and I want the output of directive in array

Comment: Directives are typically used either as graphical components, or as ways to add behavior to existing HTML elements. They don't have outputs. It seems you want a service, not a directive. Or maybe not, but since you haven't given any example of what you want and any code, it's very hard to understand what you mean.